# Copy Constructor issue in Queue Implementation using implemented LinkedList module

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Complete repository: https://github.com/mervynlee94/queue/tree/master

I have implemented LinkedList and tested my copy constructor without issue.

```
LinkedList<int> l1;
l1.insert(1,3);               // set value 3 in 1st position
l1.insert(2,7);               // set value 7 in 2nd position
l1.insert(3,9);               // set value 9 in 3rd position
LinkedList<int> l2(l1);       // copy constructor
l2.setEntry(2,5);             // set value 5 in position 2
cout<< l1.getEntry(2) <<endl; // output: 7
cout<< l2.getEntry(2) <<endl; // output: 5
```

My Queue implementation uses this LinkedList module as the data structure with code below.

```
#ifndef _LIST_QUEUE
#define _LIST_QUEUE
#include "QueueInterface.h"
#include "LinkedList.h"

template<class ItemType>
class ListQueue : public QueueInterface<ItemType> {
    private :
        LinkedList<ItemType> list; 
    public :
        ListQueue();
        ListQueue(const ListQueue& aQueue);
        ~ListQueue();
        bool isEmpty() const ;
        void enqueue( const ItemType& newEntry);
        void dequeue();
        ItemType peekFront() const;
};
#endif

template<class ItemType>
ListQueue<ItemType>::ListQueue() {

}

template<class ItemType>
ListQueue<ItemType>::ListQueue(const ListQueue& aQueue) {
    list = LinkedList<ItemType>(aQueue.list);
}

template<class ItemType>
ListQueue<ItemType>::~ListQueue() {}

template<class ItemType>
bool ListQueue<ItemType>::isEmpty() const {
    return list.isEmpty();
}

template<class ItemType>
void ListQueue<ItemType>::enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry) {
    list.insert(list.getLength()+1, newEntry);
}

template<class ItemType>
void ListQueue<ItemType>::dequeue() {
    list.remove(1);
}

template<class ItemType>
ItemType ListQueue<ItemType>::peekFront() const {
    return list.getEntry(1);
}
```

When I test the code out in main.cpp, I encountered segmentation error.

```
ListQueue<int> q1;
q1.enqueue(1);
q1.enqueue(2);
q1.enqueue(3);
ListQueue<int> q2(q1); // Set breakpoint here
q2.enqueue(5);
cout<<q2.peekFront()<<endl;
cout<<q1.peekFront()<<endl;
```

I set a debugging breakpoint on above and I realise one thing. The copy constructor in Queue implementation doesn't work properly.

The debugging value shown in copy constructor of aQueue.list and this.list varies.
[image: Debugging values]

Here is the LinkedList copy constructor implementation

```
template<class ItemType>
LinkedList<ItemType>::LinkedList(const LinkedList<ItemType>& aList) {
    Node<ItemType>* listPtr = aList.headPtr;
    if(listPtr == nullptr) {
        headPtr = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        headPtr = new Node<ItemType>(listPtr->getItem());
        Node<ItemType>* newPtr = headPtr;
        while(listPtr->getNext() != nullptr) {
            listPtr = listPtr->getNext();
            Node<ItemType>* newNode = new Node<ItemType>(listPtr->getItem());
            newPtr->setNext(newNode);
            newPtr = newPtr->getNext();
        }
    }
    itemCount = aList.getLength();
}
```

Comment: You really need to show all your code to make this reproducible.

Comment: @JasperKent got it. I am going to create a git repository for these

Comment: @JasperKent here you go. https://github.com/mervynlee94/queue/tree/master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since the copy-ctor of LinkedList is already implemented, you don't have to reimplement it - C++ will do it automatically for you.

Another **important** thing - copy constructor and copy assignment operator are **distict**.

You implemented Copy-ctor for your Queue, and in this copy-ctor you used the copy-assignment operator, and I suspect you did not implement it.

The easiest way to fix it is to simply remove the copy constructor and destructor, they are not necessary. The correct way to invoke a copy-constructor is as follows:

```cpp
template<class ItemType>
ListQueue<ItemType>::ListQueue(const ListQueue& aQueue) 
    : list(aQuquq.list) {
}
```

I have three more points to make:

1. Rule of 3 - if you declare one of copy-constructor, copy-assignment or destructor, you almost surely have to implement them all.
2. There is a bit more complicated feature in C++ called "move semantics", in case you are familiar with the term, you should consider the **Rule of 5** - the same as the previous rule, with addition of move-constructor, and move-assignment operator.
3. It seems as you are using inheritance, but I don't see the keyword `override` anywhere. If you are using `C++11` or above, consider adding the `override` qualifier to overriding methods.

And, lastly, `C++11` supports default ctors/dtors and assignment operators. If you write an empty destructor (as you do here), the cleaner syntax is to write

```cpp
class ListQueue : public QueueInterface<ItemType> {
        ...
        ~ListQueue() = default;
        ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Hmm, the implementations suppose to use interface, not inheritance.

Comment: C++ supports multiple inheritance, and interfaces and classes are not distinct, thus inheritance sometimes refer to interface implementation as well. Anyway, whay I wrote about `override` is true for interface implementations as well.

Comment: @Micheal One more question. I have to use LinkedList<int> l1 to enable copy constructor on LinkedLlist<int> l2(l1). LinkedList<int>* l1 = new LinkedList<int>() will not work on LinkedList<int>* l2(l1); Is it expected not to work with pointer style of object initialisation?

Comment: You can use both. "Pointer style" (a.k.a dynamic allocation) will preserve the lifetime of the list as long as you want, while "Value style" will preserve the lifetime of the list as long as its scope is active. Usually, scope is bounded by curly braces. (function, loop, condition, etc.). If you want the lifespan of the variable to last, use pointer, o.w. use stack.

Anyway, the correct syntax is `LinkedList<int>* l1 = new LinkedList<int>(l2) `;

Comment: Hmm I tried the correct syntax. Error with no instance of constructor "LinkedList<ItemType>::LinkedList [with ItemType=int]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (LinkedList<int> *). I guess I need to create another LinkedList constructor that accept pointer, as my current constructor is accepting normal object.

Comment: If l2 is a pointer simply write `LinkedList<int>* l1 = new LinkedList<int>(*l2);`

Comment: It works. May I know the reason behind it? Assume that the LinkedList constructor only accepts object, what is *l2? * of pointer will become ?

Comment: That's a fundemental part of C++, if p is a pointer to an object, then p stores the address of that object, and thus p is simply and address (64 bits probably). If you want to access the underlying object, the syntax is `*p`

Comment: Oh right, now I recalled it. Alright that is it. Thanks!